# Installing Tails on Verbatum Flash Drives

Tags: tails, flash

I am having trouble installing Tails 2.5 on a Verbatum 31 GB STORE-N-GO-070B6623D1E62053 USB flash drive.  Whenever I try, the installation takes a very long time and fails.  The dialog is:

> Formatting /dev/sdc1 as FAT32
>   Verifying filesystem...
>   Extracting live image to the target device...
>   Reading extracted MBR from /media/amnesia/Tails/utils/mbr/mbr.bin
>   Installing bootloader...
>   Synchronizing data on disk...
>   Unmounting mounted filesystems on '/dev/sdc1'
>   There was a problem executing the following command: `/tmp/tmpqSXJPn/syslinux  -d syslinux /dev/sdc1`.
>   A more detailed error log has been written to '`/tmp/tails-installer-W8tvV4`'.
>   Tails installation failed!

While the referenced file says:

```
sync
['/sbin/sgdisk', '--print', '/dev/sdc']Disk /dev/sdc: 60506112 sectors, 28.9 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 84759EF6-6093-4E41-840C-C4CCC52691F1
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 60506078
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 60506045 sectors (28.9 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name

sync
sync
sync
sync
/tmp/tmpqSXJPn/syslinux  -d syslinux /dev/sdc1
/tmp/tmpqSXJPn/syslinux: /dev/sdc1: No medium found
```

I tried to solve the problem by using GPart to pre-format the entire drive to FAT32, but this didn't help.

I can install Tails on other USB drives using a the tails installer on another drive on this same computer, so it probably isn't in the hardware.

I checked the list of problem USB drives before buying this one, and saw that no Verbatum drive is on the list.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The list of USBs is doesn't work with is just a list of ones its known not to work with, it's not a complete list (can't be known until they've been tested), does the USB stick do anything weird like have it's own boot options or protected partitions to serve driver software from?

Comment: Verbatim u3 removal tool, it will clean the pendrive.